# Change the place of the default application name in the nav-bar

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

Ive created MVC5 application and by defult you are getting in the nav-bar
the "application name" ,"home" "contact" etc.
the application name is in the left side of the screen and I want to change it 
to the middle how should I do that ?

Ive tried to change the following (in the bootstrap.css file)from left to center but noting happen,any idea?

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

this is the layout cshtml

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("          Application Name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        @*<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>*@
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try adding `margin-left: 50%;` or adjust it to your needs.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-left: 50%;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("          Application Name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I know its not a proper solution, but its a workaround just to help you out. Have anice day.